# Is it OK to treat the proc-macro crate in a two-crate library as implementation detail and not follow semantic versioning?

Tags: rust, semantic-versioning, rust-proc-macros

Many libraries that contain procedural macros consist of two crates: a `proc-macro` crate implementing the actual macro and a normal "main" crate that reexports or wraps the proc macro. This is done because `proc-macro` crates cannot publicly export anything other than proc macros. Assuming the main crate is called `foo`, the macro crate is usually called `foo-derive` or `foo-macros`.

This brings up a couple of questions about how to version the `proc-macro` crate. Of course, the main crate follows semantic versioning. But should the macro crate follow it as well? I don't want people to use the macro crate directly, but only through the main crate. I clearly stated that in the proc-macro crate's description. I want to treat the macro crate as an implementation detail.

In that case, can I shouldn't need to follow semantic versioning, right? The main crate would then just require one exact version via `foo-macro = "=0.0.4"`.

Is this fine? Or can something break with this approach? Are there some established best practices in the community?

Comment: Why not use the same version in both crates, even if the proc-macro doesn't change? No thinking involved, cannot go wrong.

Comment: @rodrigo I might want to make breaking changegs to the proc-macro API. Again, I want to treat it as some internal code and of course it would be fine to just change the API of internal helper methods. It just so happens that I am forced to put that internal code into a separate crate.

Comment: You don't have to follow semver, it's just a nice thing to do. If you make it clear that the crate isn't intended to be used directly, I really don't see a problem with making breaking changes like this. Internal/private crates are not uncommon.

Comment: If your tooling can handle it, I would just use a build/sequence number on the macro crate, but I am a no-nothing when it comes to rust and associated tooling.